# Is it legal to inject a @Stateful into an MDB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, message-driven-bean

Is it legal to inject a @Stateful into an MDB?

```
@Stateful
public class InteruptBean implements Interrupt {
    ....
}

@MessageDriven(...)
public class EchoTrigger implements MessageListener {
    @EJB Interrupt interrupt;

    ....
}
```

Or better phrased: Can I use a stateful EJB to pass state around in an asynchronous Event Driven Architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's "legal", but it's nonsensical.  MDBs instances are pooled like SLSBs.  The MDB will become non-functional after the SFSB times out.

It might work to explicitly create the SFSB at some point, and then pass a reference to the SFSB in the messages being sent to drive the MDB.

Comment: To get around this, I found this syntax:
    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext context;
    Interrupt interrupt = (Interrupt) context.lookup("ejb/myStateful");

Answer (score 4):

Yes it does not make sense. Because stateful session beans are meant for processing multiple requests from same client so that they have client-actions oriented processing. In this case MDB will be beans clients. MDB supports single request model. A request comes to MDB (in form of message) and it is  processed. So both types of beans don't match in processing model.

Comment: Stack overflow won't let me mark two answers as correct, but thanks!

Comment: MDB supports single request model in the same way as SLSB, but the bean instances can be pooled, so injecting an SFSB doesn't make sense to me.