# Dependency Injection of EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb

I am studying the `Dependency Injection` of `EJB` without using `CDI` and two questions have come up. I would be grateful to anyone could answer the following:

1) Is it possible to inject Session Beans (`Stateful` ot `Stateless`) with `@EJB` annotation within `Message Driven Beans`?

2) If one lets two Session Beans implement the same interface, can one inject them with `@EJB` annotation specifying only the interface name? How can one make the `Container` aware of the specific Bean class which is to be injected? For example:

```
@Remote
public interface RemoteInterface{}

@Stateless
public class BeanA implements RemoteInterfaceA{}

@Stateless
public class BeanB implements RemoteInterfaceA{}

@Stateful
public class StatefulBean{

@EJB
RemoteInterface

}
```

How can one specify which Bean is to be injected without using `CDI` and [Qualifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)Of course, you usually want to call methods from some service EJB when you receive a message in MDB.

2)It's possible, you can name your bean and then inject it by that name, see my example

```
@Stateless(name="bean1")
public class BeanA implements RemoteInterfaceA{}

@Stateless(name="bean2")
public class BeanB implements RemoteInterfaceA{}

@Stateless
public class Bean3 {

    @EJB(beanName="bean1")
    private RemoteInterfaceA bean;  
    //first bean should get injected here 
}
```

Comment: I would like to add some clarification. Although it is possible to inject a Stateful bean within a MDB , this has not much sense. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527552/is-it-legal-to-inject-a-stateful-into-an-mdb